# Check is phone call or Skype call is active iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, camera, avfoundation

I have camera view using AVFoundation and if phone call or Skype call is active then we can't use camera.

How can i check if AVFoundation will not open then i need to open other view without using camera.

if i will check this-

```
BOOL isPlayingWithOthers = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] isOtherAudioPlaying];
```

then it will not open when any other app playing audio.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2):

The `CTCallCenter` object has a `currentCalls` property which is an `NSSet` of the current calls. If there is a call then the currentCalls property should be != nil.

If you want to know if any of the calls is actually connected, then you'll have to iterate through the current calls and check the `callState` to determine if it is `CTCallStateConnected` or not.

```
#import <CoreTelephony/CTCallCenter.h>
#import <CoreTelephony/CTCall.h>

-(bool)isOnPhoneCall {
    /*
     Returns YES if the user is currently on a phone call
     */

    CTCallCenter *callCenter = [[[CTCallCenter alloc] init] autorelease];
    for (CTCall *call in callCenter.currentCalls)  {
        if (call.callState == CTCallStateConnected) {
            return YES;
        }
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: As i am understanding it will detect only phone call ?

Comment: Yes San - This only detect the Phone call.

Comment: Can we detect other VOIP calls? I need to detect if another VOIP call is in progress before opening camera using AVFoundation.

Answer (score 2):

I am using this method in Swift, Tarun answer helped me.

> **import CallKit**

```
func isOnPhoneCall() -> Bool {
    /*
     Returns true if the user is currently on a phone call
     */
    for call in CXCallObserver().calls {
        if call.hasEnded == false {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Comment: Is there any way I can check if another VOIP call is in progress? like Factime or WhatsApp call?

Answer (score -2):

Your app delegate will receive the `-applicationDidResignActive` message and your app can listen for the `UIApplicationDidResignActiveNotification`. These will be received when your app is interrupted by a call as well as in other cases where the app is interrupted, such as when the screen locks or the user presses the lock button.

For more details how to handle interruptions in [Responding to Interruptions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/HandlingAudioInterruptions/HandlingAudioInterruptions.html).

Also refer stack overflow post on [How can we detect call interruption in our iphone application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8799399/how-can-we-detect-call-interruption-in-our-iphone-application)

Comment: This will work when app is active and then got interrupted, Any other way to check on app start ?

Comment: There is no certain way to achieve it during app launch, but there is a work around by checking status bar frame, its not 100% solution. refer existing stack post [Detecting if user has in call status bar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23841418/detecting-if-user-has-in-call-status-bar)