# How to know if a phone is on calling or not in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I want to detect if a phone is on calling or not, and I searched it on internet, I didn't find a function to get the statut of a phone....Could you give me some suggestions or codes to show how can I know if a phone is on calling or not? Thank you.

my code

```
self.callCenter.callEventHandler = { (call:CTCall!) in

        switch call.callState {

        case CTCallStateDialing:
            self.toLogin = false

            break
        case CTCallStateIncoming:
            self.toLogin = false

            break
        case CTCallStateConnected:
            self.toLogin = false

            break
        case CTCallStateDisconnected:
            self.toLogin = false

            break
        default:
            self.toLogin = true
            break

    }
    }
```

My question is When I want to call someone, after entre numero of phone of someone, and he doesn't answer my call yet. I can not get this state, this state is none of the four states, do you know how?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8799399/how-can-we-detect-call-interruption-in-our-iphone-application

Comment: Thank you for your answer, ctcallcenter only has four states: `CTCallStateDialing`, `CTCallStateIncoming`,`CTCallStateConnected`,`CTCallStateDisconnected` and I can not get state when I call someone but he doesn't answer...I can't get this state, how can I do this? thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use the Core Telephony framework [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CTCallCenter/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/CTCallCenter) Ctcallcenter should do the trick

Comment: Thank you for your answer, ctcallcenter only has four states: `CTCallStateDialing`, `CTCallStateIncoming`,`CTCallStateConnected`,`CTCallStateDisconnected` and I can not get state when I call someone but he doesn't answer...I can't get this state, how can I do this? thank you

Comment: you would use a handler block and `var callEventHandler: ((CTCall) -> Void)? ` to determine if the call was disconnected or not.

Comment: Yes, I have update, please check it, Thank you